# Why does my terminal give me an error when trying to cd to another directory

Tags: oh-my-zsh, iterm

I am using iTerm and oh-my-zsh.  When I try and cd into a directory on the command line I get this message Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any parent: not found.

Here is an example: `cd laracan't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any parent: not found dock`

.zshrc

```html
# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="/Users/blake/.oh-my-zsh"

# Set name of the theme to load --- if set to "random", it will
# load a random theme each time oh-my-zsh is loaded, in which case,
# to know which specific one was loaded, run: echo $RANDOM_THEME
# See https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes
ZSH_THEME="amuse"

# Which plugins would you like to load?
# Standard plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(git)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# User configuration

# Completions Path
fpath=(/usr/local/share/zsh-completions $fpath)

## ALIASES
alias ls='ls -GFh'
alias ll='ls -al'
alias cpwd='pwd | pbcopy; pwd'

## GIT ALIASES
alias gs='git status'

# Checkout
alias co='git checkout'
alias cot='git checkout test'

# Pull and Push
alias pullo='git pull origin'
alias pusho='git push origin'

# Merge
alias gm='git merge'
alias mert='git merge test'
```

Comment: could you add your .zsh_profile and .zshrc files ?

Comment: The only context I can find for this error is related to docker-compose.  Maybe you have some  alias defined for `cd`?